# Convert Comma Separated String to Array for Text Conversion

Tags: arrays, vba, string, text-files

I am creating an application [In Access] to convert text files to excel files because my company does a lot of them.  So I created a table that I keep the File Name, Num of Cols, and a 3rd field with the common separated list of the datatypes for the columns.

Everything is working except I cannot get the comma separated list to work as an array. First, I call the ImportText File:

```
Call ImportTextFile("TestFileName", 7, ConvertStringToArray(",,,,,,2"))
```

Then I ConvertSTringToArray:

```
Function ConvertStringToArray(ByVal StringToConvert As String) As Variant

      Dim rawArray() As String
      Dim varArray() As Variant

      rawArray = Split(StringToConvert, ",")
      ReDim varArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))

      Dim i As Long: For i = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
           varArray(i) = rawArray(i)
      Next i
      ConvertStringToArray = varArray

End Function
```

Then it passes to ImportTextFile (Up until here aDataTypes is passed as an Array.):

```
Public Sub ImportTextFile(ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal iNumOfCols As Integer, Optional aDataTypes As Variant = Nothing)

    On Error GoTo Sub_Err
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application: Set xl = New Excel.Application
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sPathAndFile As String: sPathAndFile = cPath & strFileName
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sPathAndFile & ".txt", Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        If IsArray(aDataTypes) Then
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = aDataTypes
        End If
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

However, it crashes on this line:

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = aDataTypes
```

What am I missing? Why isn't this working?

The Error message that I receive is:

> Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Comment: "it crashes" - exactly what happens when it fails?  do you get an error?  If Yes what's the error message?  If you set `xl.Visible = True` you may be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Will you share the contents of `aDataTypes` or should we guess?

Comment: @VBasic2008, I gave you an example in the first code

Comment: Are you running this VBA in Excel?  If so why create a new instance of excel for this?  Also - you're passing an array of Strings, but that property expects an array of numeric `XlColumnDataType` values

Comment: @TimWilliams I added the error message that I am receiving to the bottom of my question, and I am running this code in Access.  I also added that to the original question.

Comment: Have you tried `Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)` instead of `ConvertStringToArray(",,,,,,2")`?

Comment: In addition to Tim's answer, I would use just .`..Optional aDataTypes)` (The default data type is `Variant`, the default value of a variant is `Empty`, not `Nothing`) when the *If* statement would become `If Not IsMissing(aDataTypes) Then`.

Answer (score 1):

`TextFileColumnDataTypes` expects an array of `XlColumnDataType` values, but you're passing in an array of strings.

Maybe consider reworking your array function:

```vb
Function FormatsArray(ByVal StringToConvert As String) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rawArray() As String
    Dim varArray As Variant, v

    rawArray = Split(StringToConvert, ",")
    ReDim varArray(LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray))

    For i = LBound(rawArray) To UBound(rawArray)
        v = Trim(rawArray(i))
        If Len(v) > 0 Then     'specific format supplied?
            varArray(i) = CLng(v)
        Else
            varArray(i) = xlGeneralFormat 'use default
        End If
    Next i
    FormatsArray = varArray
End Function
```